# How to create a non episodal environment in OpenAI GYM

Tags: state, environment, reinforcement-learning, agent, openai-gym

I have a non episodal environment and I want to train an agent in this environment. However, I don't want to attribute a 'done' flag to any state as I don't want my agent to identify any state as a terminal state which has no future rewards or states. In my environment, every state has an outcoming state and reward.

So my question is: How can I create such an environment using OpenAI GYM or any other API?

I have tried to attribute one of my states a done flag. Yet this could lead my agent to identify that state as a terminal state in real life as well.

Comment: I would direct you to this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311623/do-we-have-to-define-a-explicit-terminal-state-in-reinforcement-learning. TLDR: a time/action limit is implemented to end a continuous RL problem, which is seen as a sample, thus **not episode**.